# Importing an array using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `Pe` with dimensions `(2,3,3)`. I am importing Pe but then I want the code to calculate for each Pe and give me visited indices. Right now, I have to manually add `Pe.Pe[0]`,`Pe.Pe[1]` in the line `Visited_Indices,timestamps=iterate_array(0,0, Pe.Pe[0], lambda x : x < 150)`. How do I implement `Pe.Pe[i]` where `i` goes from 0 to 1?

Pe array is

```
import numpy as np
Pe = np.array([[[128.22918457, 168.52413295, 209.72343319],
        [129.01598287, 179.03716051, 150.68633749],
        [131.00688309, 187.42601593, 193.68172751]],

       [[ 87.70103267, 115.2603484 , 143.4381863 ],
        [ 88.23915528, 122.45062554, 103.06037156],
        [ 89.60081102, 128.18809696, 132.46662659]]])
print([Pe])
```

The code is

```
import numpy as np
import time
import Pe

def get_neighbor_indices(position, dimensions):
    '''
    dimensions is a shape of np.array
    '''
    i, j = position
    indices = [(i+1,j), (i-1,j), (i,j+1), (i,j-1)]
    return [
        (i,j) for i,j in indices
        if i>=0 and i<dimensions[0]
            and j>=0 and j<dimensions[1]
        ]

def iterate_array(init_i, init_j, arr, condition_func):
    '''
    arr is an instance of np.array
    condition_func is a function (value) => boolean
    '''
    indices_to_check = [(init_i,init_j)]
    checked_indices = set()
    result = []
    t0 = None
    t1 = None
    timestamps = []
    while indices_to_check:
        pos = indices_to_check.pop()
        if pos in checked_indices:
            continue
        item = arr[pos]
        checked_indices.add(pos)
        if condition_func(item):
            result.append(item)
            t1=time.time()
            if(t0==None):
                t0=t1
            timestamps.append(t1-t0)
            indices_to_check.extend(
                get_neighbor_indices(pos, arr.shape)
            )
    return result,timestamps


Visited_Indices,timestamps=iterate_array(0,0, Pe.Pe[0], lambda x : x < 150)
out = list(zip(*np.where(np.isin(Pe, Visited_Indices))))
print("Visited =",[Visited_Indices])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So what is your question/problem?

Comment: Thanks. I have now edited the post with a well-defined question.

Comment: Please post the `Pe` array as well. This way other users can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have now provided ```Pe``` array.

Comment: Why `Pe = [array...]` and not `Pe = array(...)`?

Comment: @soegaard I have edited.